# Voice Actions to Start Applications?

Tags: voice-command

I looked at [the list of Voice Actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/) on Google's website and couldn't find one for starting an application of my choice.

Is starting applications supported by Voice Actions?

If not, can a user add this feature via some setting or by an app from the market?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in Google Voice Commands can't (at this time) launch apps.

However, a [quick search on the Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=voice+command&so=1&c=apps) revealed a few possible alternatives. Here are two:

- [Cyberon Voice Commander](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyberon.cvc.AME)
- [Voice Actions](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pannous.voice.actions.free)

Comment: Thanks. Of the two applications you posted, only Cyberon advertises being able to "Launch program". I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application. For example, the "Listen to ..." ties in with several music apps like Spotify and mSpot. So far there's no way to launch an arbitrary app through voice actions if the app doesn't support one of the voice action keywords.