# Is is possible to configure the 'listen to' voice action to pull up Amazon MP3 player (or other player) rather than youtube search?

Tags: voice-command

Love the voice commands, but for me 'listen to [[blah blah]]' only ever pulls up the youtube app & searches for whatever [[blah blah]] is.  I've got the amazon mp3 app installed (as well as UberMusic) and would like for one of those two to come up instead.

I tried going into Menu > Manage Apps > Youtube & hit the 'clear defaults' button to see if I would get prompted to choose a program to respond to 'listen to' commands, but there was no prompt--I still went right to youtube.

This is a t-mobile vibrant running bionix 1.2.1 (an android 2.2 version).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the apps suggested [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12255/voice-actions-to-start-applications/12268#12268) and configure them to launch the program of choice.

Comment: Thanks much for the response.  I was really looking for something that tied in w/the native voice actions though.  I wound up setting up google music & that (sort of) responds to "listen to".  (It opens up to search results for [[blah blah]].)

Answer (score 0):

The [PowerAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&hl=en) app will respond to "Listen to..." commands.  It's a good music player if you are willing to pay about $5, but it does have a free trial.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wound up switching to google music, but maybe one of my more-preferred apps will get updated to respond to that voice action someday.